# How to find the shape parameters of of a beta distribution given the position of two quantiles?

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics

### How to find the shape parameters of of a beta distribution given the position of two quantiles?

I am trying to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the shape parameters of a beta distribution.

I know that my distribution has a median at $\frac{1}{10}$ and a 90th percentile at $\frac{1}{2}$.

## Attempt

```
Solve[{
  Quantile[BetaDistribution[α, β], 1/2]  == 1/10, 
  Quantile[BetaDistribution[α, β], 9/10]  == 1/2}, 
{α, β}]
```

`Solve` gets stuck. I have also tried `NSolve`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are fine with a numerical approximation of the values, `FindRoot` is the function you'll want to use:

```
sol = FindRoot[
  Quantile[BetaDistribution[Exp[a], Exp[b]], {1/2, 9/10}] == {1/10, 1/2},
  {
   {a, 0},
   {b, 0}
   }
  ]
BetaDistribution[Exp[a], Exp[b]] /. sol
```

> {a -> -0.787898, b -> 0.717402}
>
> BetaDistribution[0.4548, 2.0491]

In these equations I used `Exp[a]` and `Exp[b]`, because those are always positive so `FindRoot` will never accidentally try illegal parameters of the `BetaDistribution`.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try to "come close", e.g. minimize total quadratic error:

```
sol = NMinimize[
 {
   Plus[   
     (Quantile[BetaDistribution[α, β ], 1/2] - 1/10 )^2 , 
     (Quantile[BetaDistribution[α, β], 9/10] - 1/2)^2
   ]
   ,
   α ≥ 0 ∧ β ≥ 0
 }
 ,
 {α, β}
 ,
 Method -> "NelderMead" (* not needed but to make this explicit *)
]
```

> {1.03161*10^-18, {α -> 0.4548, β -> 2.0491}}